# Query select by most recent date and group line items

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

just discovered that my source data is being updated from a third-party source which I can't change.  As such, my orders file actually has all order history including updates of quantity, etc.

I am trying to create a sheet that pulls ONLY the summary values for the most recent version of the order.  The example below is an actual extract from the data set - without all the extra data.  As you can see, Bill's order was updated three times before it shipped.

I need to group on Order Number and return ONLY the last update from  09/08/2021.

There are obviously many rows (17,000) to be exact with approximately 8000 orders.  About 10% of the orders are updated like this.  Does anyone have any suggestions for grouping and reporting on the Latest date?

```
     A          B      C      D      E
Order Number | Name | Item | QTY | Updated
1001         | Bill | ABC  | 10  | 30/07/2021
1001         | Bill | DEF  | 5   | 30/07/2021
1001         | Bill | GHI  | 5   | 30/07/2021
1001         | Bill | ABC  | 10  | 07/08/2021
1001         | Bill | DEF  | 5   | 07/08/2021
1001         | Bill | GHI  | 7   | 07/08/2021
1001         | Bill | ABC  | 2   | 09/08/2021
1001         | Bill | DEF  | 4   | 09/08/2021
1001         | Bill | GHI  | 2   | 09/08/2021
```

I want to pull a query back with this group by order number for the last update and sum the QTY.

For this subset of data, the result should look like this.

`1001 | Bill | 8 | 09/08/2021`

```
=query(Orders!A1:E,"Select A, B, Sum(D), E group by A, B, E Where E = date ‘”&Text(Max(Orders!E:E),"YYY-MM-DD”)&”‘”,1)
```

I am getting an error. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY(Orders!A1:E, 
 "select A,B,sum(D),max(E)  
  Where E = date '"&TEXT(MAX(Orders!E:E), "YYYY-MM-DD")&"'
  group by A,B", 1)
```

Comment: What to do when using QUERY with IMPORTRANGE?

Comment: @AnmolDeep it would be: `=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("id", "Orders!A1:E")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4),max(Col5)  
  where Col5 = date '"&TEXT(MAX(Orders!E:E), "YYYY-MM-DD")&"'
  group by Col1,Col2", 1)` but first you need to run standalone `=IMPORTRANGE("id", "Orders!A1")` to connect your sheets