# Query filter by status on most recent date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to query my data based on date and status, by ID.

For a given date query, it should return the IDs whose most recent status (up to and including the query date) is "Active". In other words, it should return data which reflects only the IDs that were Active at the query date.

```
  A         B         C
 Date   | Status   | ID 
--------|----------|-------
4/1/22  | Inactive | Bob
5/1/22  | Active   | Sally
5/1/22  | Active   | Bob
6/1/22  | Active   | Jim
7/5/22  | Inactive | Sally
10/1/22 | Active   | Sally
10/1/22 | Inactive | Bob
```

For example, if I query `8/1/22`, it should return the following:

```
  A         B         C
 Date   | Status   | ID 
--------|----------|-------
5/1/22  | Active   | Bob
6/1/22  | Active   | Jim
```

I've tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777736/query-select-by-most-recent-date-and-group-line-items), but can't quite figure out the syntax for my specific query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT(FILTER({A:C},(A:A<=D1)),1,0),9^9,2,3,1),"Select * Where Col2='Active'")
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks. How can I also return the headers? Adding a 1 for the last argument of query() doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: use: ={{A1:C1};QUERY(SORTN(SORT(FILTER({A:C},(A:A<=D1)),1,0),9^9,2,3,1),"Select * Where Col2='Active'")}

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing within QUERY - no need for any SORT/FILTER operations as well:

```
=query(query(A:C,"select C,max(A) where A is not null and A<= date '2022-08-01' group by C pivot B",1),"select Col2,'Active',Col1 where Col2>Col3 label Col2 'Date', 'Active' 'Status'",1)
```

N.B. QUERY requires date arguments to be in ISO format.

Comment: I'm looking to return rows where _only the most recent_ row for each ID is Active. Your formula returns rows where _any_ prior date was Active. Using my example query for 8/1/22, your formula returns 5/1/22 Sally, even though her status was set to inactive on 7/5/22.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. I have edited my answer to produce your expected answer. As per my original answer, it's still accomplished entirely within QUERY (albeit with nesting required now).